# How to go to other post with next, but stay in the same category. i use portfolio plugin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, portfolio

This is what I tried but it does not work, it does not show anything

```
<?php 

    next_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE ); 

    previous_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE ); 
?>
```

this works but is not sorted by category

```
<?php

   next_post_link(); 
   previous_post_link(); 
?>
```

i use the photography theme wordpress: https://themeforest.net/item/photography-responsive-photography-theme/13304399

Answer (score 0):

```
global $post;

$post_id = $post->ID; // current post ID
$cat = get_the_category(); 
$current_cat_id = $cat[0]->cat_ID; // current category ID 

$args = array( 
    'category' => $current_cat_id,
    'orderby'  => 'post_date',
    'order'    => 'DESC'
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
// get IDs of posts retrieved from get_posts
$ids = array();
foreach ( $posts as $thepost ) {
    $ids[] = $thepost->ID;
}
// get and echo previous and next post in the same category
$thisindex = array_search( $post_id, $ids );
$previd    = isset( $ids[ $thisindex - 1 ] ) ? $ids[ $thisindex - 1 ] : 0;
$nextid    = isset( $ids[ $thisindex + 1 ] ) ? $ids[ $thisindex + 1 ] : 0;

if ( $previd ) {
    ?><a rel="prev" href="<?php echo get_permalink($previd) ?>">Previous</a><?php
}
if ( $nextid ) {
    ?><a rel="next" href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextid) ?>">Next</a><?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, only if I click on next then it goes to post page, that is not the intention

Answer (score 0):

Please try by using your taxonomy name, please see the below code.

```
$taxonomy_name = 'TAXONOMY_NAME';
$excluded_terms = array();  
next_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE, $excluded_terms , $taxonomy_name ); 
previous_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE, $excluded_terms , $taxonomy_name );
```

For more help see this link : [Previous Post link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) and [Next post Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link)

I hope it helps You.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this is not working